# minAxisAlignment.center aligns the text weirdly flutter

Tags: flutter

i am trying to align the text in center but the best result i can get is this :

[image]

text  "widget 2" is perfectly centered but text  "Widget 1" is a little bit to the left and not in the center

Here is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
  child: Column(

    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

          children: <Widget>[

            Text(
              'widget 1',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: oASDC,
                fontSize: 16.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                letterSpacing: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.more_horiz,
              ),
              iconSize: 30.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong since I am still quite new to flutter but I can find my mistake can someone please help on what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to share more code.

Comment: Hi @JigarPatel thanks for your reply , i have added more code , will that  be enough ?

Comment: It's happening because in your widget 1 part, you have added an IconButton in the Row along with it. Try removing that button and you will get widget 1 text centered properly

Comment: Looks like it is because of the `IconButton` which is taking some space on the right, so `Widget 1` is slightly on the left.

Comment: perfect thanks , i was so focused on the text("Widget 1") that i missed it